# Chrome inject script inconsistency issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Below function I did was to redirect user to a login page, and then inject a js to login the user. The code below worked well but not consistent, I hardly can debug it because the flow contain refresh of the whole page.

in my setLogin.js I try to debug with alert() wrap within $(function(){}); I found that sometime it run sometime it doesn't. So I suspect the script sometime got injected sometime not, but why is it like so?

```
chrome.tabs.update(null, {
    url: 'https://example.com/index.php?act=Login'
}, function () {

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: "jquery.js"
            }, function () {

                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                    code: 'var passedData = {username:"' + username + '",pass:"' + pass+'"}'
                }, function () {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                        file: "setLogin.js"
                    }, function () {
                        window.close(); //close my popup

                    });
                });
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @wOxxOm I use that so that to know the DOM is ready, if not i cannot do my manipulation there.

Comment: @wOxxOm I test with alert() without the `$(function(){})` is that something it trigger sometime it don't, any idea why?

Comment: @wOxxOm yes it persist still.

Comment: @wOxxOm it doesn't work at all if I add runAt, is the syntax correct?

Comment: @wOxxOm awesome that worked. In my setLogin.js also I use a function that wait for the input box to exist then continue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default scripts are injected at `document_idle` which doesn't work consistently with jQuery, probably because it's big or uses some asynchronous initialization.

Solution: explicitly specify that the injected scripts should run immediately.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jquery.js", runAt: "document_start"}, function(result) {
});
```