# How to use other JavaScript files inside a google extension script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use a markdown parser to make a preview tab in a forum, however when defining something from the JavaScript library I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Showdown is not defined`.
I've added the file to the mainifest and I can't think what else would be causing this .

./manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Forum Post Previewer",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "description":"Adds a preview tab on the post editor",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["showdown.js", "previewtab.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

./previewtab.js

```
// Adding the tab
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("nav nav-tabs");
var list = document.createElement("li");
var tab = document.createElement("a");
tab.innerHTML = "Preview";
tab.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tab");
tab.setAttribute("href", "#tab3");
list.appendChild(tab);
document.getElementById("post-editor").parentElement.firstElementChild.appendChild(list);

var md_content = document.getElementById("wmd-input-text").innerHTML;
var html_content = new (Showdown.converter().makeHtml(md_content)); //ted

var content = document.createElement("div");
content.setAttribute("class", "tab-pane");
content.setAttribute("id", "tab3");


var preview = document.createElement("div");
preview.setAttribute("id", "preview");
preview.innerHTML = html_content;

content.appendChild(preview);
document.getElementById("post-editor").appendChild(content);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Obvious question: do you have ./showdown.js available at the root of your project?

Comment: This looks like a typo question because there's no `Showdown.converter` in [that library](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown). It should be `showdown.Converter`.

Comment: I found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752868/chrome-inject-script-inconsistency-issue/32778649#32778649 it could be issue with running content script on idle, you could try "run_at": "document_end"

Comment: @Anatoliy, nope, here the scripts aren't injected via executeScript.