# Chrome Content Script Doesn't Work at First

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am developing a Chrome Extension. I have a content script that needs to be injected on to a page. This is the content script, it practically takes a message from an event page and injects it to a website then performs the search;

```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse){

    $('[name="q"]').val(msg.searchword);
    $('.btn.btn-success').click();

});
```

My event page is very long so I am trying to give the relevant part. There is a function in my event page;

```
function applySearch(search_text) {
```

Function queries for tabs with tabs.query. Then inside the callback of query, there is a big switch-case statement for programmatic injection. Here is the part that's relevant;

```
case "https://bayi.saroto.com/?p=1", "https://bayi.saroto.com/?p=15":
                console.log("Saroto case içi");
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id,{"file": "jquery-1.11.3.js", runAt:"document_start" ,allFrames:true}, scriptInCallback(tabs[i].id, "con_saroto_search.js", search_text));
```

scriptInCallback and messageInCallback Functions:

```
function messageInCallback(tabid, searcher){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabid, {searchword: searcher});
}
function scriptInCallback(tabid, scriptname, search_text){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {"file": scriptname ,  allFrames: true},
        messageInCallback(tabid, search_text));
```

This is my popup.js :

```
function hello() {
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(page){
        page.applySearch(document.getElementById('aramaKeyword').value);
    });
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

And obviously there is a textbox and a button in my popup.html

The problem is, when I open my popup and type the searchword and click to the button, even though content script has been injected (can see from developer's console of the page), it doesn't work. It only works when I open my popup again, type the keyword and click the button again.

So; content script doesn't work at first. It works at second.

Comment: See [Chrome inject script inconsistency issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32778649). Also note that chrome API is asynchronous so you should inject the second script inside the callback of the first.

Comment: Footnote: The question you've answered is about inconsistent injection. Sadly, I don't have inconsistency. It is consistent about working at the second time. It always works at the second time.

None of these solved the problem, it persists. I made nested injections through callbacks. Also added document_start. I don't believe the problem is jQuery related because I am watching the console for both event page and content script. No errors or warnings at all.

Comment: Edited, for 1 page it always works at 2nd click. When there are multiple tabs, it's just chaotic.

Comment: You're not using callbacks correctly, instead you're calling the specified function *immediately*. The correct usage is: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(......, function(results) {messageInCallback(tabid, search_text) });`

Comment: How can I send the tabid to messageInCallback inside the callback function of executeScript? tabs[i].id coming from .query is out of scope.

Comment: Make a local copy of the variable: `var _tabid = tabid;`, then `_tabid` will be  available in the subsequent asynchronous callback.

Comment: This solved the problem, please add this as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm reluctant to add an answer because there must be a good duplicate candidate for that task (can't find it now). The other issues I've helped with were generic asynchronous techniques in javascript.